# jQuery, check if clicked <a> is <td> where <td> class can be 'nickname', 'email', 'register key'

Tags: jquery

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/3ctKT/2/
But I need to check if clicked `<a>` is in `<td>` where `<td>` class can only be username, email, register key.

HTML

```
<table id="usermanagetable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Nick</th>
            <td class="nickname">
                <form>
                    <input class="plaintext" value="test" readonly="readonly" /><a href="#">Edit</a>

                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>E-Mail</th>
            <td class="email">
                <input class="plaintext" value="a5464010@drdrb.net" readonly="readonly" /><a href="#">Edit</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Register Key</th>
            <td class="registerkey">
                <input class="plaintext" value="5392e352f228d2522887aad404288ce3" readonly="readonly" /><a href="#">Edit</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td a').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().find('input').prop('readonly', false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery's [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to find out if it has the class you need

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3ctKT/6/)

```
if ($(this).parent().hasClass("email")) {
    //Do something
}
```